# Filter Object by other object with multi value

Tags: typescript

When I receive the data from .subscribe I would like filter the raw data by object with variable multiple key.
How can I do it?

```
      let oriDa: any[] = [
        {yr: 2015, mth: "Jan", A: 23, B: 29},
        {yr: 2015, mth: "Feb", A: 24, B: 30},
        {yr: 2015, mth: "Mar", A: 25, B: 31},
        {yr: 2016, mth: "Jan", A: 26, B: 32},
        {yr: 2016, mth: "Feb", A: 27, B: 33},
        {yr: 2016, mth: "Mar", A: 28, B: 34},
    ];

      let cons: any[] = [
        {
          yr: 2015,
          mth: "Feb"
        }
      ]
```

The result would be:

```
res = [{yr:2015, mth:feb, A:24, B:30}]
```

Comment: Can `cons` have multiple data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const conn = cons[0];

const res = oriDa.filter(x => x.yr === conn.yr && x.mth === conn.mth);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const filtered = oriDa.filter(el => cons.some(con => con.yr === el.yr && con.mth === el.mth));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't know object fields witch be inside cons object:

```
let filtered = oriDa.filter(el => cons.some(consEl => Object.keys(consEl).every(key => consEl[key] === el[key])))
```

the same in more readable form

```
        let filtered = oriDa.filter( el => {
        return cons.some(consEl => {
            const allKeysToCompare = Object.keys(consEl);
            return allKeysToCompare.every(key => consEl[key] === el[key]);
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter()` method for the task. However it depends on if you wish to use more than one object in `cons` variable.

```js
var oriDa = [
  {yr: 2015, mth: "Jan", A: 23, B: 29},
  {yr: 2015, mth: "Feb", A: 24, B: 30},
  {yr: 2015, mth: "Mar", A: 25, B: 31},
  {yr: 2016, mth: "Jan", A: 26, B: 32},
  {yr: 2016, mth: "Feb", A: 27, B: 33},
  {yr: 2016, mth: "Mar", A: 28, B: 34},
];

var cons = [
  {
    yr: 2015,
    mth: "Feb"
  }
]

console.log(oriDa.filter(item => {
  if (item.yr === cons[0].yr && item.mth === cons[0].mth) {
    return item;
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have multiple objects in the cons array, then you may use the filter and some array methods
we can do something like that

```
let filterdData = oriDa.filter(item => {
    return cons.some(con => {
        return item.yr === con.yr && item.mth === con.mth
    });
});
```